# Is it possible to limit number of connections used by Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, nopcommerce

I've noticed that on a NopCommerce site we host (which uses Entity Framework) that if I run a crawler on the site (to check for broken links) it knocks the entire webserver offline for a few minutes and no other hosted sites respond. This seems to be because Entity Framework is opening 30-odd database connections and runs hundreds of queries per second (about 20-40 per page view).

I cannot change how EF is used by NopCommerce (it would take weeks) or change the version of EF being used, so can I mitigate the effects it has on SQL Server by limiting how many concurrent connections it uses, to give other sites hosted on the same server a fairer chance at database access?

What I'm ideally looking to do, is limit the number of concurrent DB connections to about 10, for a particular application.

Comment: Entity Framework itself does not manage multiple concurrent connections. If you point it to a connection string then it will create (or grab from the pool if you're using ADO.NET connection pooling, which is on by default) one connection per context instance and dispose that connection when the context is disposed. You can change this in your application by managing connections yourself and passing the connection to the context instance when it is created. Doing so is something that the application architecture must support; it's not something that EF is controlling.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is use the `Max Pool Size` setting in the connection string.  This limits the maximum number of connections in the connection pool, and I *think* this means that's the maximum number of connections the application will ever use.  What I'm not sure of though, is if it can't get a connection from the pool, will it cause an exception.  I've never tried limiting the connections in this manner.

Here's a litle reading on the settings you can put in a ADO.NET connection string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

And here's a little more reading on "Using Connection Pooling":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding "Max Pool Size=10" to my connection string but it still seems to use around 40 connections :(

Comment: Max pool size setting does not limit the created connections. It only limits the connections per pool. The only thing you can so far is to use Semaphore before opening a connection.